# Filtering ListView with multiple controls JavaFX

Tags: java, list, listview, javafx, filtered

I am developing a project which has a pane to create an Event(Meeting) in my program. 
This pane has a ListView of Rooms which needs to constantly be updated using a list of available filters in the interface (TextView's, CheckBox's, DateTimePicker, Spinner), for example if I write "1" in the name textview and set capacity to 10 it is supposed to apply that 2 filters to the listview and only show the rooms which name contains "1" and capacity=10.

Here is a picture of my pane.
[image]

What I have done is adding a listener to each of the control's text or value property, but the problem is when I apply more than 1 filter it doesn't apply the 2 filters together, and I will need to apply multiple.

This is the code I've done for 2 of the filters, but like I said I will need more.

```
    listRooms = new ListView<>();
    FilteredList<Room> filteredList= new FilteredList<>(roomsList, data -> true);

    
    txtRoomName.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
        String filter = txtRoomName.getText();
        if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.setPredicate(s -> true);
        }
        else {
            filteredList.setPredicate(s -> s.getName().contains(filter));
        }
    });

    spCapacity.valueProperty().addListener(obs->{
        int filter = spCapacity.getValue();
        if(filter == 0) {
            filteredList.setPredicate(s -> true);
        }
        else {
            filteredList.setPredicate(s -> s.getCapacity() == filter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Using more than one choicebox to filter listview in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248446/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a method to generate the predicate.  Collect ALL of the filter criteria there, regardless of which one changed:

```
txtRoomName.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
    calculatePredicate();
});
spCapacity.valueProperty().addListener(obs->{
    calculatePredicate();
});

private void calculatePredicate() {
    String filterTxt = txtRoomName.getText();
    int filterCap = spCapacity.getValue();

    filteredList.setPredicate(s -> {
        boolean txtMatch = filterTxt == null || filterTxt.isEmpty() || s.getName().contains(filterTxt);
        boolean capMatch = filterCap == 0 || s.getCapacity() == filterCap;
        return txtMatch && capMatch;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really haven't understood how the setPredicate() method work's, I need to go through some documentation on it and probably get some sleep too ;)

Comment: The thing to remember about the filtered list predicate is that the list is only recalculated when the predicate is changed to a new predicate - if variables used by a single predicate are changed in a manner that would make it filter differently, there is no event to trigger re-computation of the filtered list.  Calling setPredicate with a new predicate instance is one way to trigger that.  Also, there can be only one predicate set, so it must include all of the conditions you need.  Any prior predicate is forgotten.